# A connection between the confluent hypergeometric function and Bessel functions.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, special-functions, hypergeometric-function

Let $b$ and $w$ be real parameters subject to $b\neq 1$. Let $x \in {\mathbb R}$. 
Define:
\begin{equation}
{\mathfrak N}(w,b):= \frac{2^{\frac{1}{2 (1-b)}+1} \left(\frac{1}{b-1}\right)^{\frac{1}{2 (b-1)}} w^{\frac{1}{2 (b-1)}+1}}{\frac{1}{2 (b-1)}!} \quad (I)
\end{equation}
Then the following identity holds:
\begin{eqnarray}
&&x^{\frac{1-b}{2}} e^{-\frac{i w x^{1-b}}{b-1}} {\mathfrak N}(w,b) \cdot \, _1F_1\left(\frac{3}{2}+\frac{1}{2 (b-1)};2+\frac{1}{b-1};\frac{2 i w x^{1-b}}{b-1}\right)=\\
&&\!\!\!\!\left( \left(2 w x^{1-\frac{b}{2}}+i x^{b/2}\right) J_{\frac{1}{2 (b-1)}}\left(\frac{w x^{1-b}}{b-1}\right)-i w x^{1-\frac{b}{2}} \left(J_{\frac{1}{2 (b-1)}-1}\left(\frac{w x^{1-b}}{b-1}\right)-J_{1+\frac{1}{2 (b-1)}}\left(\frac{w
   x^{1-b}}{b-1}\right)\right)\right)
\end{eqnarray}
The code below serves as a verification:

```
b = RandomReal[{-5, 5}]
w = RandomReal[{1, 20}]; x =.; Clear[NN];
NN[w_, b_] := (1/(-1 + b))^(1/(2 (-1 + b))) 2^(1 + 1/(2 (1 - b)))
    w^(1 + 1/(2 (-1 + b)))/(1/(2 (-1 + b)))!;
fp[x_] := (-I w x^(
      1 - b/2) (BesselJ[-1 + 1/(2 (-1 + b)), (
         w x^(1 - b))/(-1 + b)] - 
        BesselJ[1 + 1/(2 (-1 + b)), (
         w x^(1 - b))/(-1 + b)]) + (2 w x^(1 - b/2) + 
        I x^(b/2)) BesselJ[1/(2 (-1 + b)), (w x^(1 - b))/(-1 + b)]) /
   NN[w, b];
fm[x_] := (-I w x BesselJ[-1 + 1/(2 - 2 b), (w x^(1 - b))/(-1 + b)] + 
     I w x BesselJ[1 + 1/(2 - 2 b), (
       w x^(1 - b))/(-1 + b)] + (2 w x + I x^b) BesselJ[1/(2 - 2 b), (
       w x^(1 - b))/(-1 + b)]) x^(-b/2) ;

yp[x_] := 
  E^(-((I w x^(1 - b))/(-1 + b))) x^((1 - b)/2)
    Hypergeometric1F1[3/2 + 1/(2 (-1 + b)), 
    2 + 1/(-1 + b), ((2 I w x^(1 - b))/(-1 + b))];
ym[x_] := 
  E^(-((I w x^(1 - b))/(-1 + b))) x^((1 - b)/2)
    HypergeometricU[3/2 + 1/(2 (-1 + b)), 
    2 + 1/(-1 + b), ((2 I w x^(1 - b))/(-1 + b))];
b = RandomReal[{-5, -1}];
w = RandomReal[{1, 20}]; x = Range[0, 0.1, 0.0001];
ListPlot[First[{Re[#], Im[#]} & /@ {fp[x]/yp[x]}]]
```

[image]

We have obtained the identity above by analyzing solutions to the following ODE:
\begin{equation}
\left[\frac{d^2}{d x^2} + \left( \frac{1-b^2}{4 x^2} - \imath (-1+b) w x^{-1-b} + w^2 x^{-2 b}\right)\right] \cdot y(x)=0
\end{equation}
The ODE in question is on one hand produced from the Whittaker ODE by rescaling the variables appropriately. On the other hand the ODE in question corresponds to a certain gauge transformation ([Gauge transformation of differential equations.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2952857/gauge-transformation-of-differential-equations)) of the Bessel ODE. As a matter of fact both sides of equation $(I)$ are solutions to our ODE above and the nomalization constant ${\mathfrak N}(w,b)$ ensures that the the values of the function and its derivative at zero match.

Note that if we take $b=5/4$ we retrieve the following entry http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric1F1/03/02/13/0020/ in Wolframs database as a special case.

Now having said all this my question would be how would one go about deriving the identity in question using some alternative approach?

Comment: This is very interesting, but why is your code leading to division by zero?

Comment: The range of $x$ values includes zero and it just happened that the parameter $b$ was bigger than one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Introducing the notations:
\begin{equation}
 \nu=\frac{1}{2(b-1)}\: ; z= i w \frac{x^{1-b}}{b-1}
\end{equation} 
we have to evaluate
\begin{equation}
 Y= \,_1F_1\left(\nu+ \frac{3}{2};2\nu+2;2z\right)
\end{equation}
Using the [derivative formula](http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric1F1/20/01/04/0001/) for the Kummer confluent hypergeometric function:
\begin{align}
 Y&=\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\,_1F_1\left(\nu+ \frac{1}{2};2\nu+1;z\right)\\
 &=\Gamma(\nu+1)\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\left[ 2^\nu e^zz^{-\nu}I_\nu(z)\right]\\
 &=2^\nu\Gamma(\nu+1)e^z\left( z^{-\nu}-\nu z^{-\nu-1} \right)I_\nu(z) \\ 
 &\qquad\qquad+2^{\nu-1}\Gamma(\nu+1)e^zz^{-\nu}\left[I_{\nu-1}(z)+I_{\nu+1}(z) \right]\\
 &=2^{\nu-1}(\nu)!z^{-\nu}e^z\left\lbrace2\left( 1-\nu z^{-1} \right)I_\nu(z)+
\left[I_{\nu-1}(z)+I_{\nu+1}(z) \right]
 \right\rbrace
\end{align} 
where the [hypergeometric representation](http://functions.wolfram.com/Bessel-TypeFunctions/BesselI/26/01/03/0001/) for the modified Bessel function $I_\nu$ and an expression of its [derivative](http://functions.wolfram.com/Bessel-TypeFunctions/BesselI/20/01/02/0003/) were used. Introducing the [representation](http://functions.wolfram.com/Bessel-TypeFunctions/BesselI/27/01/0002/)
\begin{equation}
 I_\mu(z)=I_\mu\left( i w \frac{x^{1-b}}{b-1} \right)=i^\mu J_\mu\left( w \frac{x^{1-b}}{b-1}   \right)
\end{equation} 
in the latter expression should give the proposed identity.